# Access denied trying to read bootstrap action file - AWS EMR & S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-iam

I wish to achieve the following

1. Create S3 bucket that contains EMR bootstrap script and config file
2. Apply policy to this bucket so that only EMR default roles can access it along with specific admin users
3. EMR bootstrap action runs when cluster starts that accesses S3 bucket to retrieve script and config file and execute on EMR nodes

Here is the policy I have applied to the S3 bucket. I am using the **NotPrincipal** statement so it will deny access to everyone except the listed arn's

```
{
  "Id": "policy1",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/user1@mydomain.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/user2@mydomain.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/EMR_DefaultRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-restricted-access",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-restricted-access/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I then am trying to create an EMR cluster via the C# AWS SDK that includes a bootstrap action to run a script from the following location

```
s3://bucket-restricted-access/config/runscript.sh
```

However, as soon as the cluster starts I get an error

> Terminated with errors - Access denied trying to read bootstrap action
>   file 's3://bucket-restricted-access/config/runscript.sh'

Is the EMR cluster using the assumed permissions from the EMR_EC2_DefaultRole role to try and retrieve the bootstrap action?

If not, is there another user/role that I need to add to the S3 bucket policy to fix the permissions issue?

Comment: This looks to be on correct path. Is this error in the bootstrap logs of a node of the cluster or just in the cluster status?

Comment: Its in the cluster status. No logs are generated for the cluster.

Comment: Then that would indicate service role.  Verify that EMR_DefaultRole is being used as service role (see cluster details). If so, you could launch a simple Linux instance using that role to test.

Answer (score -2):

The EMR cluster is launched with security group ElasticMapReduce-master and ElasticMapReduce-slave

The access key and secrete key which you use to create EMR should have permission to access the s3 bucket which has your bootstrap script

Comment: The access key does have permission to access the S3 bucket - I manually checked with a S3 client. It can access the restricted folder and open the script file within it. Am still getting access denied error when trying to start cluster.